# Triggering capacitive touch on a touch device

Tags: arduino-uno, wires

As you can see in the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JDgDMBquBw0), it is possible to trigger a touch with arduino. I have tried a couple of methods but with no success.

- I have a wire soldered on to a coin which is being used to trigger
  the touch.
- I tried to directly connect pin 2 from arduino to the    coin (no
  touch applies)
- I tried to connect a relay and transistor,    seems    necessary for
  this project but I didnt get it to work either.

I will say I have very little knowledge of relay/transistor and the wiring part of it, so Im guessing thats where the problem is.

My parts:

Transistor P2N2222A:
http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/P2N2222A-D.PDF

Relay:
JZC-11F

Sketch used:

```
  void setup() {
  digitalWrite(2,LOW);
}

void loop() {

  pinMode(2, INPUT);
  delay(500);

  pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
  delay(500);

}
```

If possible please provide a frizting schematic showing how to connect.

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/63950/arduino-trigger-an-iphones-touch-screen-with-no-human-interaction

Answer (score 1):

Capacitive touch screens are design (both the hardware and software) to work with human fingers and human like movements.  It could be that you are not only working against the physical aspects of influencing capacitance at the screen location you are interested in controlling, but also the software which is trying to reject noise and "unwanted touches".

That said, [this stack exchange question / answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/60385/how-to-use-a-capacitive-touch-screen-without-a-human-hand) addresses some of your questions and even proposes an (untested) circuit to try.  I would suggest to skip the "accepted" answer and read the answer with the highest score.

Based on the above response, I would suggest changing your strategy.  I might try connecting the Arduino directly to the metal probe.  Then changing the software to alternate between putting a negative then positive voltage potential on the metal probe.  Avoiding using the Atmel's input or high impedance configuration.  I might also try a smaller metal probe that covers a smaller area of the target device.  Perhaps something that is conductive and easily reforms to a flat screen as if it were a finger tip.  Something like a small ball of aluminum foil. Also, make sure that there is nothing else touching the screen like tape or a stray wire.  Such objects may cause the target's software to consider all touch events as noise or as "unwanted touches".